# Search result fluctuations

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I have bunch of collections with documents and i have encountered so,ething starnge. When I execute same request few times in a row result change consecutively
It would be fine if it's small fluctuations, but count of results changes on ~75000 of documents
So I have a question what's going on

My request is:

```
POST mycollection/mytype/_search
{
  "fields": ["timestamp", "bool_field"], 
  "filter" : {
      "terms":{
        "bool_field" : [true]
    }
  }
}
```

results are going like this:

```
=> 148866
=> 75381
=> 148866
=> 75381
=> 148866
=> 75381
=> 148866
```

When count is 148k 
I see some records with `bool_field: "False"` in Sense

Comment: Look at _cat/shards and see if the number of documents belonging to primaries and replicas is the same. The idea is to see if the primary shard and its replicas have the same number of docs.

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: @AndreiStefan How documents can be different? Wouldn't Elastic throw Conflict excaption if i try to update docs this way?

Comment: I said number of documents, not documents themselves.